# how to get response headers in django , when using rest framework response

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, frameworks

I am trying to get response headers as i see in postman .  I am using response.headers which works fine on my local server , but when hosted it gives error .

So I tried using response.items() to find the response headers , which works well .

But I am looking over the headers i get on postman like

[image]

Please let  me know if there is any lead in this regard

Comment: Please provide the `views.py`. How do you use `response.items()`